# DataReader within try block causing potential null reference error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exception

There is probably is simple fix for this but I currently have code similar to

```
dim dr as dbDataReader

try
      dr = connection.getDataReader(sql_str)
Catch ex as sqlClientException
     log.error(ex)
finally 

  if not IsNothing(dr) then
    dr.close
  end if
end try
```

However Visual Studio still warns me that the

```
if not IsNothing(dr) then
        dr.close
      end if
```

Can cause a NullReferenceException. What is the best way to mitigate this? I can't move the declaration into the try block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Explicitly initialize the dr declaration to Nothing as such:

```
Dim dr As DbDataReader = Nothing
```

And the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

If `GetDataReader` throws, `dr` will not be assigned and will still have its initial value. VB.NET does initialise references to `Nothing`, but the compiler will not let you rely on that.

If using .NET 2.0, I would recommend a `Using` statement:

```
Using dr As DbDataReader = connection.GetDataReader(sql_str)
    Try
        ' Do something with dr '
    Catch ex As SqlClientException
        log.error(ex)
    End Try
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. In the `finally` statement, as long as you check to make sure your objects are not null, it won't throw a null reference exception based on what happens in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly, how VB.NET initialize variable, but in C# you must set "dr" some value/reference before you use them somewhere.

I think this should work:

```
dim dr as dbDataReader

try
      dr = connection.getDataReader(sql_str)
Catch ex as sqlClientException
     log.error(ex)
     dr = Nothing ' there is the change '
' finaly block is not necesary '
end try

if not IsNothing(dr) then
  dr.close
end if
```

Comment: What exactly is 'does not work'? Compile error ( if so, send the message please )? Or it doeas not work in run-time ( thrown exception? if so, send the exception.ToString() please ).

I haven't VB.NET compiler on my current computer :(

Comment: The compile-time warning that the original poster's code produces remains after applying your suggestion.